# I'm having a dataframe like this how can remove these special chars using spark scala?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

```
df.map(x => x.replace("^", "").replace("{", "").replace("}", ""))
```

output file

```
name,age,year
aravind,22,1995
venagt,23,1895
raj,23,1955
```

Comment: what is the output of `df.show`

Comment: Whats the input?

Comment: ^name^,^age^,^year^
^{aravind}^,^22^,^1995^
^{venagt}^,^23^,^1895^
^raj^,^23^,^1955^

Answer (score 0):

To replace the special characters in Spark, you'll have to write the character in the following form =>  "\\ + special_character"

For example, if you want to replace ^, {, } in the column "name", you can do the following:

```
df.withColumn("name", regexp_replace(col("name"), "\\^", "")).withColumn("name", regexp_replace(col("name"), "\\{", "")).withColumn("name", regexp_replace(col("name"), "\\}", ""))

Output for the column will be:
+-------+
|name   |
+-------+
|raj    |
|aravind|
|venagt |
+-------+
```

If you want to do the above for all the columns in the DataFrame, you can simply run the following code:

```
scala> var df = Seq(("^{raj}^","^{23}^","^{1995}^"), ("^{aravind}^","^{22}^","^{1995}^")).toDF("name", "age", "year")

scala> df.show(false)
+-----------+------+--------+
|name       |age   |year    |
+-----------+------+--------+
|^{raj}^    |^{23}^|^{1995}^|
|^{aravind}^|^{22}^|^{1995}^|
+-----------+------+--------+

scala> df.columns.foreach(x => {df = df.withColumn(x, regexp_replace(col(x), "\\^", "")).withColumn(x, regexp_replace(col(x), "\\{", "")).withColumn(x, regexp_replace(col(x), "\\}", ""))})

scala> df.show(false)
+-------+---+----+
|name   |age|year|
+-------+---+----+
|raj    |23 |1995|
|aravind|22 |1995|
+-------+---+----+
```